# If $X$ and $Y$ are uniform$(-1,1)$, how can I find the distribution of $W=X^2+Y^2$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, self-learning

If $Y$ and $X$ are independent uniform (-1,1) random variables, I would like to derive the distribution of $W=X^2+Y^2$.

At first I thought that I could use the CDF technique and a geometric argument, that is  divide the area of a circle with radius $\sqrt{w}$,   $0<w<2$ by $4$, the area of the $2$ by $2$ square that constitutes the support of $X$ and $Y$.

The problem with that approach is that the resulting pdf:

$$f_W (w)=\begin{cases} \pi /4,& 0<w<2 \\
0, & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases} $$

does not integrate to $1$.

Could you please help me understand where I went wrong here and how to arrive at the right answer?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note: for example, the circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$ contains points outside the square $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$.

Comment: Do you what a double integral is? Use that to find your answer.

Comment: This might be of use: [distribution of $X^2+Y^2$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767340/distribution-of-x2-y2).

Comment: @GEdgar Indeed, thank you. The double integral is however nontrivial. After performing the first integration I also need to evaluate $ \int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{w-x^2}dx$. Any hints here?

Comment: That's a standard problem in trigonometric substitution. Draw a right triangle whose hypotenuse is length $\sqrt{w}$, where one acute angle is $\theta$ and a side of length $x$ is opposite to it. Then $x=\sqrt{w} \sin(\theta)$, $dx = \sqrt{w} \cos(\theta) d \theta$, and $\sqrt{w-x^2}=\sqrt{w}\cos(\theta)$, so the whole integral is $\int w^{3/2} \cos(\theta)^2 d \theta$, which is routine. That said, I somewhat doubt you wrote the integral correctly if you got that as an intermediate step.

Comment: Hint: if $r \geq 0$, to have $X^2+Y^2 \leq r^2$, you need $-r \leq X \leq r$ and $-\sqrt{r^2-x^2} \leq Y \leq \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$. So your integral needs to be modified somewhat.

Comment: @Ian Yeah you are right of course. Thank you very much.

Comment: I made an error earlier, it should have been $\int w \cos(\theta)^2 d \theta$, of course (I included the factor of $\sqrt{w}$ from $x$ by mistake).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your geometric approach will work. Draw a picture. If $0\lt w\le 1$, we get a circle that if fully inside the square on which the joint density "lives," and as you saw things are straightforward.

If $1\lt w\lt 2$, we need to find the area of the part $D$ of the square that is in the disk of radius $\sqrt{w}$. Join the centre of the circle to the $8$ points where the circle meets the sides of the square. This divides our region $D$ into $8$ parts, $4$ isosceles triangles and $4$ circular sectors.

We find the combined area of these and divide by $4$, or equivalently find the area of a triangle and a circular sector, and add.

To find the area of a triangle, let us for example find the two places where $x^2+y^2=w$ meets the line $x=1$. This is at $y=\pm \sqrt{w-1}$. So the base of the triangle is $2\sqrt{w-1}$, and therefore the area is $\sqrt{w-1}$.

The central angle of each triangle is $2\arctan(\sqrt{w-1})$, and therefore the angle of each of the $4$ circular sectors is $\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(\sqrt{w-1})$. For the area, divide by $2$.

Comment: Thank you, this is the kind of answer I had been looking for. I like picturing this kind of problems geometrically and getting away with the formality of integration.

Comment: You are welcome. I have the same feeling about geometry. Integration is good, of course. But to set up the right integral, one has to pay careful attention to the geometry.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\delta\pars{w - x^{2} - y^{2}}\,{\dd x \over 2}\,
{\dd y \over 2}}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 4}\,2\int_{0}^{1}2\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{%
{\delta\pars{y + \root{w - x^{2}}} \over 2\verts{y}}
+{\delta\pars{y - \root{w - x^{2}}} \over 2\verts{y}}}\,\dd y\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\left. \half\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over \root{w - x^{2}}}\,
\right\vert_{w\ >\ x^{2}\,,\root{\vphantom{\Large A}w - x^{2}}\ <\ 1}
=\left. \half\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over \root{w - x^{2}}}\,
\right\vert_{w - 1\ <\ x^{2}\ <\ w}
\\[3mm]&=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
\half\int_{0}^{\root{w}}{\dd x \over \root{w - x^{2}}} & \mbox{if} & 0 < w < 1
\\[2mm]
\half\int_{\root{w - 1}}^{1}{\dd x \over \root{w - x^{2}}} & \mbox{if} & 
1 \leq w < 2
\\[2mm]
0 && \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.
\\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
{\pi \over 4} & \color{#000}{\mbox{if}} & 0 < w < 1
\\[2mm]
\half\,\arcsin\pars{{2 \over w} - 1} & \color{#000}{\mbox{if}} & 
1 \leq w < 2
\\[2mm]
0 && \color{#000}{\mbox{otherwise}}
\end{array}\right.}
\end{align}

> [image]